# Can I run a Grails war under Tomcat in a machine without JDK (Only JRE)?

Tags: web-services, tomcat, grails, java

Can I run a Grails war under Tomcat in a machine without JDK (Only JRE)?

I have a Grails app that works fine in `grails run-war` or in a separate tomcat server in the same computer.

When I deploy this .war on a server that has a JDK, I have no problem.

When I try to do this in a server that only has a JRE, the application won't work.

**specs**:

***grails app***:

- grails 1.2.2.
- groovyWS,
- i18n templates

***dev pc***:

- win xp sp3
- 2gb ram
- athlon 64 x 2
- java: build 1.6.0_20-b02 ( JDK )
- tomcat: 6.0.24 ( test 1 )
- tomcat 5.5 ( test 2 )

***server that do not work***:

- so: windows server 2003
- app server: tomcat 2.2 as a service ,
- java: 1.6.0.18 , ( ONLY JRE )
- wsclient:  groovyws-0.5.1.jar  ( minimal ) ( and all depenedncies added by hand )

**Stacktrace**

```
[ERROR] IOException during exec() of compiler "javac". Check your path environment variable.
2010-03-18 15:55:23,522 [http-8080-1] ERROR dynamic.DynamicClientFactory  - Could not compile java files for http://SOMEURL/SOMEWS.asmx?WSDL.
2010-03-18 15:55:23,553 [http-8080-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - "org.tempuri" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "org.tempuri" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:197)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.createClient(DynamicClientFactory.java:349)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.createClient(DynamicClientFactory.java:196)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.createClient(DynamicClientFactory.java:175)
    at groovyx.net.ws.AbstractCXFWSClient.createClient(AbstractCXFWSClient.java:198)
    at groovyx.net.ws.WSClient.initialize(WSClient.java:107)
    at groovyx.net.ws.IWSClient$initialize.call(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can I run a Grails war under Tomcat in a machine without JDK (Only JRE)?: the question will be: " can i run war with Web services in a machine without JDK": the answer will be no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GroovyWS needs javac to create stubs dynamically, so it needs JDK.

Comment: "can i run war with Web services in a machine without JDK": the answer will be no. as wanderson said , jdk is needed, another thing its that it must be in the path.

Answer (score 0):

JSP's need to be compiled (even if they're in the war), so there needs to be a compiler for it. You can't just use the JRE. This is for Java stuff, for groovy its most likely the same.

Comment: so it might be a JDK its not on path just java_home.
( can't check, the guy @ servers its off for today =/ ).
i guess the question will be: 
can i use a grails war with a java_home not on path ?